# How to extend partition size in linux(ubuntu 9.04)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extend partition size in linux(ubuntu 9.04) ?](https://superuser.com/questions/58497/how-to-extend-partition-size-in-linuxubuntu-9-04)

Hi Friends,

I am using Ubuntu 9.04 in vmware for my programming purpose. I previously had 12GB of virtual harddisk, my partition scheme was as follows,

---

8GB  Primarimary Partition for **(/)**

2GB  logical extended partition for **home**

2GB logical extended partition for **swap**

---

Now I need 20 GB more space for my **(/)** Partition. So I added 20GB to my virtual harddisk so now, my partition scheme was as follows,

---

8GB  Primarimary Partition for **(/)**

2GB  logical extended partition for **home**

2GB logical extended partition for **swap**

20GB unpartotioned space.

---

can you please tell me is it possible to make my Primary partition **(/)** to 28 GB, If yes tell me how?

It would be great if you can tell me some GUI software, otherwise for commandline please elaborate little more. :)

Comment: that's not programming related!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you will be able to use a graphical tool like GParted in vmware (the traditional way is to run it from a Live CD). But this article details the command line steps: [How To Resize ext3 Partitions Without Losing Data](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions_p2) (assuming you're using ext3).

Comment: Yes, I am using ext3. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: AFAIK a VM can boot gparted just the same as a real machine.

Comment: gparted works in vmware.

Comment: Ok, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Safest way is to create a new empty drive in VMware.
Mount it under linux in vmware.
Copy over the linux installation (see "cp -a" )
Disconnect the original disk.

Comment: can i copy linux installation completely, I mean does symbolic links and pipe and other stuffs will get easily copied?

Comment: I wouldn't do that

Comment: Rather than "cp -a" I would use the dump and restore utilities.  You may have to install them, since not all distros install them by default.

Comment: I did it with gparted live cd, It is now working fine.